# How to get query string parameters from POST request in CGI Perl script?

Tags: perl, post, cgi, query-string

You can get query param in CGI script with this code:

```
#!C:\Perl64\bin\perl.exe

use CGI;

my $cgi = CGI->new();

my $file = $cgi->param( "file" );
print "Content-Type: text/plain\n\n";

my $text = do {
    open(my $f, "<:encoding(UTF-8)", $file)
      or die("Can't open \$filename\": $!\n");
    local $/;
    <$f>
};

print $text;
```

but this don't work if request is POST, I'm sending this request using fetch API:

```
await fetch('cgi-bin/script.pl?file=..\foo.php', {
   method: 'POST',
   body: 'Some Text'
}).then(r => r.text());
```

if I open the script in Browser I get content of the file. Is there a way to tell CGI module to get params from QueryString instead of POST data? or any other raw way to parse Query String without CGI module in Perl?

Comment: `$cgi->url_param('file')`  http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html#MIXING-POST-AND-URL-PARAMETERS

Comment: @ernix thanks, you can add this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems weird to make a `POST` request with all of the data in the URL. Why not just make a `GET`?

But, anyway, CGI.pm has you covered. There's a section in the documentation called **[Mixing post and url parameters](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI#Mixing-post-and-url-parameters)** which says the following:

> ```
> my $color = url_param('color');
> ```
>
> It is possible for a script to receive CGI parameters in the URL as well as in the fill-out form by creating a form that POSTs to a URL containing a query string (a "?" mark followed by arguments). The param() method will always return the contents of the POSTed fill-out form, ignoring the URL's query string. To retrieve URL parameters, call the url_param() method. Use it in the same way as param(). The main difference is that it allows you to read the parameters, but not set them.

Comment: Will this work without `use CGI; my $cgi = CGI->new();`? You didn't use `$cgi->`

Comment: @jcubic: Yeah, that works too. But I've never really seen the point of using CGI objects. Whoever needs more than one CGI object in a program?

Comment: @jcubic: Also, please read [CGI::Alternatives](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Alternatives) and [Please Don't Use CGI.pm](https://perlhacks.com/2018/11/please-dont-use-cgi-pm/).